# Better Methods for moving JButtons

Tags: java

I try to code software for my selfmade food order terminal and 
found a method to make it happen but it needs so much writing. 
I think there might be a better way of doing this.

I code to serve max 100 customer and every one of them got there own `Jpanel` in which they but there food (`JButtons`) in. For every possible single food item order I use one while loop.

Well this way I need to write close to 100000 `while` loops.

Maybe you guys have a suggestion to do this without so much code.

This is how 50 of these 100000 look like:

```
            gemüse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {



                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                    Preis = Preis + gemüsepreis;
                    labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf(Preis));
                    while (kunde == 1) {

                        while (brgemü == 1) {gemüicon1.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon1);gemüicon1.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 2) {gemüicon2.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon2);gemüicon2.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 3) {gemüicon3.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon3);gemüicon3.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 4) {gemüicon4.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon4);gemüicon4.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 5) {gemüicon5.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon5);gemüicon5.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 6) {gemüicon6.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon6);gemüicon6.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 7) {gemüicon7.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon7);gemüicon7.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 8) {gemüicon8.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon8);gemüicon8.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 9) {gemüicon9.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon9);gemüicon9.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 10) {gemüicon10.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon10);gemüicon10.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 11) {gemüicon11.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon11);gemüicon11.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 12) {gemüicon12.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon12);gemüicon12.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 13) {gemüicon13.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon13);gemüicon13.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 14) {gemüicon14.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon14);gemüicon14.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 15) {gemüicon15.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon15);gemüicon15.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 16) {gemüicon16.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon16);gemüicon16.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 17) {gemüicon17.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon17);gemüicon17.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 18) {gemüicon18.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon18);gemüicon18.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 19) {gemüicon19.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon19);gemüicon19.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 20) {gemüicon20.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon20);gemüicon20.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 21) {gemüicon21.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon21);gemüicon21.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 22) {gemüicon22.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon22);gemüicon22.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 23) {gemüicon23.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon23);gemüicon23.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 24) {gemüicon24.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon24);gemüicon24.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 25) {gemüicon25.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon25);gemüicon25.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 26) {gemüicon26.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon26);gemüicon26.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 27) {gemüicon27.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon27);gemüicon27.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 28) {gemüicon28.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon28);gemüicon28.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 29) {gemüicon29.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon29);gemüicon29.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 30) {gemüicon30.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon30);gemüicon30.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 31) {gemüicon31.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon31);gemüicon31.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 32) {gemüicon32.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon32);gemüicon32.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 33) {gemüicon33.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon33);gemüicon33.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 34) {gemüicon34.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon34);gemüicon34.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 35) {gemüicon35.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon35);gemüicon35.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 36) {gemüicon36.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon36);gemüicon36.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 37) {gemüicon37.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon37);gemüicon37.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 38) {gemüicon38.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon38);gemüicon38.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 39) {gemüicon39.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon39);gemüicon39.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 40) {gemüicon40.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon40);gemüicon40.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 41) {gemüicon41.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon41);gemüicon41.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 42) {gemüicon42.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon42);gemüicon42.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 43) {gemüicon43.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon43);gemüicon43.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 44) {gemüicon44.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon44);gemüicon44.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 45) {gemüicon45.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon45);gemüicon45.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 46) {gemüicon46.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon46);gemüicon46.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 47) {gemüicon47.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon47);gemüicon47.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 48) {gemüicon48.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon48);gemüicon48.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 49) {gemüicon49.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon49);gemüicon49.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                        while (brgemü == 50) {gemüicon50.setVisible(false);Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon50);gemüicon50.setVisible(true);brgemü++;return; }
                                }
```

Kunde means customer in german.
For every single fooditem I got 100 of these codeblocks, 
and we have around 18 fooditems.

Comment: Show your class structure.

Comment: I not quite sure what you mean. I got one Main class with 32511 lines of code.

Comment: You are programming in Java which is OO language. If you have a single class with that many lines of code, then you obviously skipped the design process.

Comment: Iam new to programming. I will look more into the basics of Java. Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: You probably want to take a break and go over some tutorials and maybe write a few simpler examples first. A main class with 32k lines of code, while loops instead of ifs, etc, is madness. It's great that you've persevered and got that far until you got stuck at the possibility of having to write 100000 lines of code. But programming is about making the computer do the work for you. It's like you started digging a subway tunnel with just your hands and are wondering why it's taking so long.

Comment: If (no pun intendet) i manage to implement the help of you guys to cut my code most of my project is finished. But i realized that i was going way to fast on that one. I will step back after this and try to work on java basics. 
Thanks for the tipp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not that familiar with Java UI classes, so I will use `T` to mark the type of the `gemüiconXX` objects. Besides that, here is at least a more-elegant way to address the matter:

I'd use a Map to keep the icons:

```
Map<Integer, T> iconsMap = new HashMap<Integer, T>();
```

Then in the constructor or component initialization, I will write put the icons in the map. The idea is for this to happen once:

```
iconsMap.put(1, gemüicon1);
....
iconsMap.put(50, gemüicon50);
```

Then your "ugly" code will become this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Preis = Preis + gemüsepreis;
    labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf(Preis));
    while (kunde == 1) {     
        T gemüicon = iconsMap.get(brgemü++);
        gemüicon.setVisible(false);
        Bestellpanel.add(gemüicon);
        gemüicon.setVisible(true);
        return; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While is used when something should be repeated multiple times but not a fixed amount of. Since you are returning in every while loop, what you want to use is either an if-statement or a switch-statement. Also in your case you probably want to store all `gemüicons` in an array or list and just access it using `brgemü` as the index. That way you only would have a few lines of code.

```
if(kunde == 1)
{
   gemüsearray[brgemü].setVisible(false);
   Bestellpanel.add(gemüsearray[brgemü]);
   gemüsearray[brgemü].setVisible(true);
   brgemü++;
   return;
}
```

Comment: I will look more into this. Thanks :)